# Change crispy forms string representation

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

Crispy forms use the string representation of objects provided by the **str** method of the objects' class: I need to change this behaviour (please, help me).

In my crispy form the labels of the choices in a CheckboxSelectMultiple() field populate from the default **str** method of the objects represented. The set of objects is defined in a list containing ids, with those ids crispy calls the **str** methods.

Is it possible to write a custom string representation (for instance as a class' @property) and tell crispy to use that instead?
If yes, which point in the pipeline would give the best programmer's practice (models/views/forms/template) ?

[this image is just a dummy example for better illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1TJM.jpg)
Overriding the default **str** method provides the desired labelling (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996912/django-crispy-multichoices-form-foreignkey-is-printing-object-instead-of-obj) post) but is totally unacceptable because of side effects.

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):

    nice_name_for_forms = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    
    @property
    def label_from_instance(self):
        return '%s' % (self.nice_name_for_forms)
```

views.py

```
school_list = School.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
form = MyForm(request.POST, school_list=school_list)
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyForm
        fields = '__all__'      
        labels = {'schools' : 'My Schools'}
                
        widgets = {'schools' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.school_list = kwargs.pop('school_list')        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['schools'].queryset = self.fields['schools'].queryset.filter(id__in=self.school_list).distinct()

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.use_custom_control = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(CheckboxAllFieldCompact('schools', wrapper_class='col-4 col-md-2'))
```

checkbox_all_field.html

```
<!-- crispy/checkbox_all_field.html -->
{% load crispy_forms_field %}
{% load i18n %}
<div id="div_checkbox_all_{{ field.html_name }}" class="no-form-control control-group {{ wrapper_class }}">
    <div class="controls" style="max-height:250px;overflow:auto">
        <label for="{{ field.name_for_label }}" class="label_title inline">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <br />
        <label class="block">
            <button id="check_all_{{ field.html_name }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" actif="false">{% translate 'Select all' %}</button>
        </label>
        {% crispy_field field %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanest way for changing the string representation of objects used in crispy forms' fields involves writing a `@staticmethod label_for_schools` in `forms.py` within the relevant class:

```
#forms.py

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = MyForm
        fields = '__all__'      
        labels = {'schools' : 'My Schools'}
                
        widgets = {'schools' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

    @staticmethod
    def label_for_schools(self):
        if self.nice_name_for_forms:
            return '%s' % (self.nice_name_for_forms)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.school_list = kwargs.pop('school_list')        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['schools'].queryset = self.fields['schools'].queryset.filter(id__in=self.school_list).distinct()

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.use_custom_control = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(CheckboxAllFieldCompact('schools', wrapper_class='col-4 col-md-2'))
```